# Is there any method to decrease tensorflow lite invoke time in c++?

Tags: c++, performance, tensorflow-lite, invoke

**System information**

1. windows 10, x64
2. TensorFlow version: 2.7.0
3. Python version: 3.9.5
4. Bazel version : 3.7.2
   5.GCC/Compiler version : 11.2.0

I run a custom CNN tflite model on tensorflow lite using c++ where i got invoke time 2.5 second and same tensorflow model version i run on python where i got 1.19 second . As i know c++ is more faster than python then what is the issue ?

> **Note :**
> because of commercial reason i can't give the code snapshot.

Comment: EDIT: I thought you are using TFLite python API, not TF Python API.


Are you testing this on a mobile device or a workstation. TFLite is focused more for on device deployment. You can leverage TFLite benchmark tool to get more details about why it is slow 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark#readme


Original Reply: You will need to provide more details about what you are doing so we can help you. TFLite Python API uses the C++ API underneath. So i think you are either measuring the latency wrong, or they are not doing the same thing.

Comment: Hello, have you fixed this problem and if yes, how? Because I also faced with the same issue..

Comment: @KarimNosseir basically i tried to invoke TFlite model using C++ where i got the latency which is more than TF model (run on python). i know that C++ is more faster than python that's why i asked the question. But i read some blog about TFlite speed in C++ .I noticed that TFlite model inference is less faster than TF model. That's the issue of TFlite and TF model

Comment: @AinurZhappass i didn't found any clue except tried to optimized the matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

TFLite focuses more on on-device performance. So it is not as optimized when you run it on a x86 machines compared to arm devices for example.